# Let $X$ be Poisson r.v. with $\lambda$ find $f(x)$ such that $E[f(X)]=\lambda \log (\lambda)$

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory, poisson-distribution

I am looking for a function $f(x)$ such that 
\begin{align}
E[f(X)]=\lambda \log (\lambda) \quad  \text{ for all } \lambda \ge 0 \tag{$*$}
\end{align}
where $X$ is a Poisson random varaible with parameter $\lambda$. Note, we are looking for a function idenpendent of $\lambda$.

**Here are some thoughts:** 
\begin{align}
\lambda \log (\lambda) = E[f(X)]= \sum_{k=0}^\infty f(k) \frac{\lambda^k e^{-\lambda}}{k!} 
\end{align}
Therefore, we have that 
\begin{align}
e^{\lambda} \lambda \log (\lambda) =  \sum_{k=0}^\infty f(k) \frac{\lambda^k }{k!}= \sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k \frac{\lambda^k }{k!} \tag{$**$}
\end{align}
where in the last step I defined $f(k)=a_k$.

Now, this is the point where I am a bit stuck.

It doesn't look like the expression in $(**)$ can hold as I don't think the function $g(x)=e^x x \log(x)$ can be written as a Maclaurin series. 
These lets me to conclude that there is no function $f(x)$ such that $(*)$ holds.

Comment: Well, by linearity, $\mathbb{E}(\log(\lambda ) X)=\log \lambda \mathbb{E}(X)=\lambda \log \lambda$, since $\log \lambda$ is a constant, yes? So, you might need an extra condition to avoid such trivial answers of $f(x)=\log(\lambda) \cdot x$

Comment: @LoveTooNap29 Yeah, I want a function independent of $\lambda$.  Let me add this.  Thank you, this example did not occur to me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To be precise, we want to find $f:\mathbb{N}_0\to\mathbb{C}$ such that
$
E\left[|f(X)|\right]<\infty,
$ and $$
E[f(X)]=\lambda\log\lambda,\quad\forall \lambda\ge 0.
$$

Now, we can write
$$
\sum_{k=0}^\infty f(k)\frac{\lambda^k e^{-\lambda}}{k!}=\lambda\log\lambda,
$$or equivalently
$$
\sum_{k=0}^\infty f(k)\frac{\lambda^k}{k!}=\lambda e^\lambda\log\lambda .
$$ The LHS is by the assumption an absolutely convergent power series for all $\lambda\ge 0$. Then this implies that it can be extended uniquely to some entire function $F(\lambda)$. Since $F(0) = \lim\limits_{\lambda\to 0^+}\lambda e^\lambda \log \lambda =0$, $G(\lambda)=\frac{F(\lambda)} {\lambda}$ also defines an entire function. Now, we have
$$
e^{-\lambda}G(\lambda) =\log\lambda
$$ for all $\lambda>0$, but $\lim\limits_{\lambda\to 0^+}e^{-\lambda}G(\lambda)=G(0)\neq \lim\limits_{\lambda\to 0^+}\log\lambda=-\infty.$ This leads to a contradiction. Therefore, there does not exist $f$ such that $E[|f(X)|]<\infty$ and $E[f(X)]=\lambda \log \lambda$ for all $\lambda\ge 0$.

Comment: Thanks. Why does $G(0)\neq -\infty$? Is it because otherwise, it  is equal to zero at that point?

Comment: @Boby That is because $G(z)=\frac{F(z)}{z}$ must have a removable singularity at $z=0$ (note that $F$ is already an entire function vanishing at $0$) and hence $G$ is also entire.

Comment: Also, how important is the assumption $E[|f(X)|]<\infty$ in this proof?  Can there exists a function such that that $E[f(X)]=\lambda \log(\lambda)$ while  $E[|f(X)|]=\infty$ ?

Comment: Expectation is 'defined' only for those $f$ such that $E\lvert f(X)\rvert <\infty.$ Otherwise, expected value is not even defined and there is nothing we can say about it. So it is a matter of the definition of an expecation (or integral with respect to a measure).